# Is there a reliable way to detect if a native (C++) function has been (indirectly) called by a specific .Net assembly

Tags: c++, .net, windows, winapi, odbc

First, let me explain my problem.

I work on a framework used to build ODBC drivers, and there is a bug in the .Net framework, the part which deals with ODBC drivers. I would like to put a workaround for the bug into our framework, and I'd like to make it automatic. To do this, I would need to check if the ODBC connection in question was created from a specific .Net assembly.

My idea, at a high level was at the point of creation of the connection, to walk the stack, and see if the module which was calling into the ODBC driver manager (i.e. ODBC32.DLL) was that specific .Net assembly.

Our code is native, and written in C++. I already know how to walk the stack and check modules with CaptureStackBackTrace/CreateToolhelp32Snapshot/Module32First/GetNextModule, but I think a 'naive' approach could be flakey (not to mention that .Net assemblies != Win32 modules). Is there already some 'supported' way of doing this? Unfortunately, I don't think simply detecting managed code on the stack (which is what I guess *would* exist, if anything close to what I need does) is enough, I need to specifically check that a specific assembly is calling into ODBC32.dll, from lower down the stack.

Even better would be if I could detect the version of the assembly, to deactivate the workaround if the issue is ever fixed.

Something that would be almost as good, would be to detect the presence of the .Net runtime if it was activated in the current process, and to activate the workaround in that case (without causing any side effects like loading the framework if it wasn't already loaded). It could have false positives, but it would be a good default.

Edit: This is the bug in question https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/671144/overflowexception-from-systemdataodbcodbcdatareade.html

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly on the .NET side is causing problems for your native code? Since you want to workaround the issue on your native side, that presumes that your native code can detect the buggy condition to begin with, right? Can't you just make that check automatic, without trying to walk the stack and resolve modules and such on every connection? Or maybe tie the workaround to a configuration item in your native code that can be turned on and off at runtime as needed?

Comment: The problem on the .Net side is that it causes an exception if a value in the returned metadata is 'too large'. I don't want to limit what metadata can be returned across the board to prevent this issue.

Comment: @remy the configuration option is a possibility, but it's not ideal

Answer (score 0):

I think the best workaround would be editing .NET's `System.Data.Obdc.dll` using a .NET assembly editor like [Reflexil](https://github.com/sailro/Reflexil) and placing it in the same folder as your executable - it should load it instead of the one in your system files.

If you want to avoid that, here's an idea of how I would handle it:

Even if you walk the stack, you'll only see pointers to where JIT compiled the function's code, which means you'll have to figure out a way to find out where `BuildMetaDataInfo()` is compiled.

Here's the C# code that would grab that pointer, but you mentioned that your application is native C++, so you might have to figure out some other way to do this.

```cs
typeof(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader).GetMethod("BuildMetaDataInfo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer()
```

Once you got the function pointer, depending on how you plan on fixing this, you could either

- Hook `BuildMetaDataInfo` and write your own / figure out a workaround
- Hook `SQLColAttributeW` and `BuildMetaDataInfo`. Use `BuildMetaDataInfo`'s hook to detect whether `SQLColAttributeW` is called or by it or not, or use stack walking but that might be a nightmare considering how JIT compiles code.

Pseudocode for a `SQLColAttributeW` hook:

```cpp
std::map<DWORD, bool> activeCalls;
__declspec(noinline) void  __stdcall BuildMetaDataInfoHook() {
    activeCalls[GetCurrentThreadId()] = true;
    OriginalBuildMetaDataInfo(); // Call the original .NET function
    activeCalls[GetCurrentThreadId()] = false;
}

__declspec(noinline) void WINAPI SQLColAttributeWHook(SQLHSTMT, SQLUSMALLINT, SQLUSMALLINT, SQLPOINTER, SQLSMALLINT, SQLSMALLINT*, SQLLEN*) {
    if (!activeCalls[GetCurrentThreadId()])
        return OriginalSQLColAttributeW(...);

    // Insert fix here

    return OriginalSQLColAttributeW(...);
}
```

`SQLColAttributeW` is the native function called by `BuildMetaDataInfo()` that seems to be causing your issue according to what I read on the bug report you posted.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your second bullet point?

Comment: Another issue is that we don't control the application, only the ODBC Driver,so I don't think we can replace the framework code (it's loaded before us)

Comment: And I wanted to highlight that the dotnet code doesn't call directly into us, it does so by calling into the ODBC Driver manager, which proxies our driver.

Comment: I've added some pseudocode(untested) to explain better what I meant. As for replacing the framework code, if your framework is loaded as a dependency, you might be able to get away with a TLS Callback which hooks CreateFileW and use that to redirect to a framework. TLS Callbacks are called before the process's own entry point.

Comment: We're going to be linked into an ODBC Driver, which is a native dll that is loaded at runtime via the ODBC Driver manager when someone attempts to create an ODBC connection.

Comment: Unless you can make a workaround work with a hook to `SqlColAttributeW`, I doubt there's any reliable way to do this in your current situation, due to the fact that you are loaded at runtime and that you don't have access to managed code.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'don't have access to managed code'?

Comment: I meant using .NET code (C#, C++/CLI, etc). Without access to .NET's reflection features it's hard to reliably get data needed for hooking or modifying existing .NET code.

Comment: We _could_ have access to C++/CLI if it could help.

Comment: You could likely use the GetFunctionPointer() on BuildMetaDataInfo(as I've written in the answer) and write a JMP instruction there to your own function. I'd recommend using [Minhook](https://github.com/TsudaKageyu/minhook) to do this. You could also go the code modification and/or injection route, if you are familiar with x86/x64 assembly.